# Given the function $f(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt[3] {1-x^3}}$ find $\underbrace {f(f(\cdots f(19)\cdots))}_{95}$

Tags: functions, contest-math, recursion

Given the function $$f(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt[3] {1-x^3}}$$ find $$\underbrace {f(f(\cdots f(19)\cdots))}_{95}$$

My try:

Define $$f^n(x)=\underbrace {f(f(\cdots f(x)\cdots))}_{n}$$

We see that  $$f(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt[3] {1-x^3}}$$

$$f^2(x)=\frac {\sqrt[3] {1-x^3}}{-x}$$

$$f^3(x)=x$$

And again $$f^4(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt[3] {1-x^3}}$$

Hence $$f^{3k+2}(x)=\frac {\sqrt[3] {1-x^3}}{-x}$$

Substituting $k=31$ and $x=19$ I can find $$\underbrace {f(f(\cdots f(19)\cdots))}_{95}$$

So am I going on the right path.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing it correctly (using the periodicity).

Comment: @AlvinJin Thanks for checking it

Comment: YES, Since $f^3(x)=x$ for all $x\ne 1,$ we have $f^{95}(x)=(f^3)^{31}(f^2(x))=f^2(x).$

Answer (score 2):

As you have already said there are only 3 interactions, then it goes back to the original function:
\begin{align}
f_0 = \underbrace{f(x)}_1&=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3] {1-x^3}} = \left(\frac{1}{1-x^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
f_1 = \underbrace{f(f(x))}_2&= \left(\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{1-x^3}\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \left(1 - \frac1{x^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
f_2 =\underbrace{f(f(f(x)))}_3 &= \left(\frac{1}{1-\left(1 - \frac1{x^3}\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = x  
\end{align}
If you count from $0$, so it's the $95$-th interaction equals $f_{94}$. It follows $94 \pmod 3 = 1$,which implies $f_{94} = f_1$:
$$\underbrace{f(f(\cdots f(19)\cdots))}_{95} = f_{94} = f_1 =\left(1 - \frac1{19^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} $$

Comment: I don't think the answer is 19. The answer seems to be $$\sqrt[3] {\left( 1-\frac {1}{x^3}\right) }$$

Comment: @Manthanein you have a sequence of 3 functions that are repeated $f_0,\,f_1\,f_2,\,f_0,\,f_1,\,f_2 \cdots$. 
If you count up to 95, what function do you have?

Comment: I guess f(1)...

Comment: the division by zero is undefined.

Comment: @Manthanein you're right!. if you count from 0, the 95 interaction is in fact the unction $f_{94}$ Thus $94 \pmod 3 = 1$

Comment: Mathematica code:`f[x_] := 1/(1 - x^3)^(1/3); Nest[f, x, 95] /. x -> 19` says:`(3*254^(1/3))/19 = (1 - 1/19^3)^(1/3)`. Answer is  correct.`:)`